# Show that $\phi(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, absolute-convergence

Consider the alternating series $$\phi(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}}.$$ The exercise asks me to show that this series does not converge absolutely on $\mathbb{R}$, converges uniform on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have proved the first two, but got stuck in the last one. To show $\phi(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, we need to show that $$(1)\ \ u_{n}(x):=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}(1+\frac{u^{2}}{n})^{n}}\ \ \text{is differentiable on}\ \ [-R,R];$$ $$(2)\ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}'\ \ \text{converges uniformly to some}\ \ g\ \ \text{on}\ \ [-R,R];$$ $$(3)\ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x_{0})\longrightarrow\phi(x_{0})\ \ \text{for some}\ \ x_{0}\in[ -R,R],$$ where $R$ is arbitrarily fixed. Then, $\phi$ is differentiable on $[-R,R]$ and $\phi'=g$. But $R$ is arbitrary, so taking $R\rightarrow\infty$ finishes the proof.

$(1)$ is clear and the derivative is $$u_{n}'(x)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}2x}{\sqrt{n}(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n+1}},\ \ \text{for}\ \ n\geq 1.$$

$(3)$ is also clear. Since $(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}\nearrow e^{x^{2}}$ and $\sqrt{n}\nearrow \infty$, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n}}\searrow 0.$ Hence the alternating series converges pointwise on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ by the alternating series test.

**However, I don't know how to show $(2)$.** I want to use the following fact:

> If a alternating series passes the alternating series test, then we must have $$\Big|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_{k}\Big|\leq |a_{n}|.$$

I used this fact to prove the uniform convergence. However, the denominator of $u_{n}'$ does not have the same monotonicity:

$\sqrt{n}\nearrow\infty$, but $(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n+1}\searrow e^{x^{2}}$. Thus, even though on $[-R,R]$, $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{n}(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n})^{n+1}}\rightarrow 0,$$ it is unknown that if this convergence is monotonically decreasing, but this is required by the alternating series test.

Is there any other way to prove the uniform convergence of $\sum u_{n}'$? or I am missing something?

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Below is how I proved the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, take $N:=\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}-1$, then as the alternating series passes the alternating series test, we use the referred fact above, and see that for all $n\geq N$, and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Big|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}u_{k}(x)\Big|\leq |u_{n+1}(x)|&=\Big|\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n+1})^{n+1}}\Big|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\Big|\dfrac{1}{(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n+1})^{n+1}}\Big|\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&\leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}-1+1}}\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

As I argued before, this proof requires the alternating series to pass the alternating series test, but the coefficient of $u_{n}'(x)$ may not decrease to $0$. (It indeed goes to $0$).

Comment: How did you show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$?  If you have show that, then it should not be difficult to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n'(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$ also.  One more thing … $\left(1+\frac{x^2}n\right)^{n+1}$ does not monotonically increase to $e^{x^2}$ for all $x$.

Comment: @MarkViola I used the fact I mentioned in this post, and bound the tail series, using $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}-1$. But to use this fact, I have to show $a_{n}(x)$ monotonically decreases to $0$. This works for $u_{n}(x)$, but as I argued in the post, this doest not work for $u_{n}'(x)$.

Comment: @MarkViola Let me edit the post to add how I proved the uniform convergence.

Comment: @MarkViola edited just now.

Comment: Jacob, it is not correct that $\left(1+\frac{x^2}n\right)^{n+1}$ monotonically decreases to $e^{x^2}$.  For example, take the case $x=2$.  Then, $\left(1+\frac{4}n\right)^{n+1}\le e^4$ for all $n\ge 1$.  But $\left(1+\frac{x^2}n\right)^{n+1}$ does not monotonically increase to $e^{x^2}$ for all $x$ either.  Take $x=1$ for example.

Comment: @MarkViola ah. okay. Thank you! I assume this due to the accepted answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720615/show-that-f-nx-nx1-xn-is-uniformly-bounded-on-0-1-for-all-n-geq

Comment: You're welcome.  The relationship is true for $x=1$, but not true in general.

Comment: @MarkViola do you know if $(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n+1}$ converge to $e^{x}$? Perhaps it converges but just not monotonically?

Comment: Yes Jason.  [See This Answer I posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) in 2015.

Comment: Jason, the sequence $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ increases monotonically for all $x>-n$ and converges to $e^x$.  But interestingly, we cannot assert that the sequence $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n+1}$ is monotonic for all $n$ for every fixed $x$.  There are values of $x$ for which it increases, values of $x$ for which it decreases, and values of $x$ for which is not monotonic for all $n$.  Try analyzing these two distinct sequences and supplement by plotting them.  Let me know what you find.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola okay. I don't really know this concept you such a deep way. I will analyze them and come back to you.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you so much !!

Comment: You're welcome Jason.  My pleasure.  And have a look at the answer in the link I provided to you.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399419/proving-that-en-log1-fracx2n-is-monotonic-in-n/2399441#2399441) is another one.

Comment: @MarkViola no problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $2x/\sqrt{n}$ is monotonically decreasing with respect to $n$  and uniformly convergent to $0$ on $[0,R]$, We also have $-2x/\sqrt{n}$ montonically decreasing with respect to $n$ and uniformly convergent to $0$ on $[-R,0)$. Hence, the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2x}{\sqrt{n}}$$

converges uniformly by Dirichlet's test on both $[-R,0)$ and $[0,R]$, and, therefore, on $[-R,R]$.

The sequence $(1 + x^2/n)^{-(n+1)}$ is eventually monotone  and uniformly bounded for $x \in [-R,R]$. Therefore, by Abel's test we have uniform convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2x}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{n} \right)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you. Nice answer.

Comment: @MarkViola Hope you also stay safe and healthy. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @rrl There is a problem here.  Note that $a_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{x^2}n\right)^{n+1}$ does not monotonically increases for all $x$.  For example, take $x=1$ and surely $a_{n+1}(1)\le a_n(1)$.  Hence, its reciprocal does not satisfy the condition of Abel's test for all $x\in [-R,R]$ for all $R$ (that is, uniformly bounded AND decreasing).

Comment: @MarkViola:  It only needs to be monotone (increasing or decreasing).  For ordinary convergence that only has to happen eventually.  So it may be a snag for uniform convergence but I have to check.

Comment: I believe that Abel requires the second term (in the product that forms the general term of the series) to be monotonic and decreasing.  This is not true here for all $x$.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel's_uniform_convergence_test) is a statement of Abel's test for UC of a series.  Indeed, if $g_n(x)$ is monotonically decreasing for $x\in E$ and if $\sum_n f_n(x)$ UC on $E$, then $\sum_n g_n(x)f_n(x)$ is UC on $E$.

Comment: I know that is sufficient. But there is another condition when $\sum |g_n(x) - g_{n+1}(x)|$ is uniformly convergent. This the case when the sequence $g_n$ is uniformly convergent and monotone so that $|g_n - g_{n+1}| = (g_n - g_{n+1}$ and the sum is telescoping.

Comment: Using summation by parts, $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) g_k(x) = S_n(x) g_{n+1}(x) + \sum_{k=1}^nS_n(x)(g_n(x) - g_{n+1}(x))$. Here  $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$ converges uniformly to $S$ and $g_n(x)$ converges uniformly. So UC is guaranteed if $\sum_{k=1}^nS_n(x)(g_n(x) - g_{n+1}(x))$ converges uniformly.  Since $S_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded this reduces to showing that $\sum_{k=1}^n|g_n(x) - g_{n+1}(x)|$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: @RRL Alas, we don't have monotonicity of the $g_n$ sequence (not for all $x$).  But you assert that $g_n$ will be monotone eventually, correct?  That should be trivial to show.

Comment: We also have $x$ in a compact set.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(x)$ converges locally uniformly, here is a quick proof: Write

\begin{align*}
u_n'(x)
= -\frac{2x}{1+\frac{x^2}{n}} u_n(x)
= -2x u_n(x) + \frac{2x^3}{n+x^2} u_n(x).
\end{align*}

Then on each interval $[-R, R]$,

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-2x) u_n(x)$ converges uniformly, and
- $\left| \frac{2x^3}{n+x^2} u_n(x) \right| \leq \frac{2R^3}{n^{3/2}} $ uniformly in $n$ and $x$, and so, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x^3}{n+x^2} u_n(x)$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test.

Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n'(x)$ also converges uniformly on $[-R, R]$.

---

**Addendum.** Another purpose of this answer is to hint a much more general idea: You may split the sum into two parts: conditionally convergent part (which is easier to control) and absolutely convergent part.

In OP's case, we easily check that, for each $R> 0$,

$$ \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x^2}{n})^{n+1}} = e^{-x^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$

uniformly in $n$ and $x \in [-R, R]$, where the implicit bound of $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$ depends only on $R$. Using this, we may write

$$ u_n'(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2xe^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{n}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right), $$

which can be used to easily prove the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n'(x)$ over $[-R, R]$.

Comment: (+1)  Nicely presented.  And I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy my friend.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you. I did not realize that I can think of this problem in the way you suggested.